# Joins and Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables I need to join together. Once I join the first two, I'm going to have two columns, let's call them `A` and `B`.

The relationship between `A` and `B` is many-to-many. So we can have:

```
A    B
1    1 
1    2
2    1
2    3
```

Then, I need to join with a third table on the B column, giving me:

```
A    B    C
1    1    5 
1    2    6
2    1    9
2    3    2
```

Now for my final result I only want one row for each unique `A` value, and I want to select that row based upon the `MAX` `C` value across that given `A`.

So in this example the final value would be:

```
A    B    C
1    2    6
2    1    9
```

I have the following query which works as expected, but I am fairly certain it is not the best way of doing it:

```
SELECT 
    Temp.A,
    Temp.B,
    Temp.C1
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        T1.A, 
        T2.B,
        MAX(T3.C) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.A) AS C1
    FROM T1 
        INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.X = T2.X
        INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.B = T3.B) Temp
    INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.B = Temp.B
WHERE Temp.C1 = T3.C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query can be simplified:

1. You don't need `select distinct` in the subquery.
2. You don't need to join back to `T3`.
3. You can select the `C` value in the subquery.

Here is the revision:

```
SELECT Temp.A, Temp.B, Temp.C
FROM (SELECT T1.A, T2.B, T3.C, MAX(T3.C) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.A) AS C1
      FROM T1 INNER JOIN
           T2
           ON T1.X = T2.X INNER JOIN
           T3
           ON T2.B = T3.B
     ) Temp
WHERE Temp.C1 = Temp.C
```

Do note that if `T3` has duplicate maximum values, then this will return duplicates.  To get just one, you can use `row_number()` instead:

```
SELECT Temp.A, Temp.B, Temp.C
FROM (SELECT T1.A, T2.B, T3.C,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.A ORDER BY T3.C DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM T1 INNER JOIN
           T2
           ON T1.X = T2.X INNER JOIN
           T3
           ON T2.B = T3.B
     ) Temp
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```